# uniform_int_distribution using a list instead of a range of values

Tags: c++, c++11

I've looked up the documentation and examples after trying to run my code but was unable to find a method to feed a list into the `uniform_int_distribution`. Is this not even possible then?

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to randomly pick an item from a given list without using `srand()` or `rand()`?

Comment: Use `uniform_int_distribution` to generate an integer in `[0, list.size())` and pick the item at that index.

Comment: There's an example at the bottom of [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). It should be trivial to adapt it using TC's suggestion above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a random number in the correct range using a `uniform_int_distribution`, then pick the element of the list using `std::next`, like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());
    std::list<char> lst{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> uid(0, lst.size() - 1); // range [0, size-1]
    std::size_t pos = uid(rng); // random index in the list
    auto elem = *std::next(lst.begin(), pos); // pick up the element
    std::cout << elem << std::endl; // display it
}
```